# Case statements in termux

Tags: termux

I tried this and failed. Does case statements exist in termux?

```
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash
case in "$1"
    start)
            echo 'var1'
            ;;
    stop)
            echo 'var2'
            ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

Termux does indeed support `case`, but your syntax is incorrect. This, instead, works.

```
case "$1" in
 start)
  echo 'var1'
  ;;

 stop)
  echo 'var2'
  ;;
esac
```

Adding a blank line between the `start)` and `stop)` blocks is just a stylistic choice.

Comment: Tnx. Got it. Where I can generally investigate about termux borders: what is supported and what - not.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk Being Termux's default shell Bash, you can assume that all of the builtins and shell commands you would be able to call during a Bash session on a Linux machine be working. If what concerns you are what packages are able to be installed, either see the project's homepage, or directly ask its author, which maintains said packages.